# Using element of list both as string and integer

Tags: python, string, loops, integer

Is there a way to use the elements of a string-list first as strings and then as int?

```
l = ['A','B','C']

for n in l:
    use n as string (do some operations)
    convert n to int(element of NG)
    use n as int
```

I tried to Play around with range/len but I didnt come to a solution.

Edit2:

This is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

NG = ['A','B','C']

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [6,5,4,3,2,1]

for n in NG:
    print(n)
    dflist = []
    df = pd.DataFrame(l)
    dflist.append(df)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
    dflist.append(df2)
    df = pd.concat(dflist, axis = 1)
    df.plot()
```

The Output are 3 figures that look like this:
[image]

But I want them to be in one figure:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

NG = ['A','B','C']

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [6,5,4,3,2,1]

for n in NG:
    print(n)
    dflist = []
    df = pd.DataFrame(l)
    dflist.append(df)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
    dflist.append(df2)
    df = pd.concat(dflist, axis = 1)
    ax = plt.subplot(6, 2, n + 1)
    df.plot(ax = ax)
```

This code works, but only if the list `NG` is made out of integers `[1,2,3]`. But I have it in `strings`. And I Need them in the Loop.

Comment: what you mean by *"first as strings and then as int"* ? Can you post a sample o/p ?

Comment: Do you mean the index when you say `as int`?

Comment: Do you need the intergers equivalent to the ascii table? That mean A = 65

Comment: Sorry, I made it unclear. First I Need the string of the list. Then I Need the string's index for the plot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the index in Python 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to access both the element of list and its index?**

That is the real question as I understood mainly from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49727251/using-element-of-for-loop-both-as-string-and-int#comment86469134_49727251). And it is a pretty common and straightforward piece of code:

```
NG = ['A', 'B', 'C']

for i in range(len(NG)):
    print(i)
    print(NG[i])
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. Sorry for the poorly written question

Answer (score 1):

Here is my 2 cents:

```
>>> for n in l:
...     print ord(n)
...     print n
... 
65
A
66
B
67
C
```

## To convert back to char

```
>>> chr(65)
'A'
```

Comment: Is there a way to convert the strings to their index?

Comment: care to explain? I didn't get your question.

Comment: I Need the string as well as its index (of the list). Example: I Need the 'B' as well as its index -> 2

Comment: >>> for index,c in enumerate(str):
     ...     print(c,index)
     ... 
     ('H', 0)
     ('E', 1)
     ('L', 2)
     ('P', 3)
     >>>

Comment: you can use list (i.e. l) as well instead of string(i.e. str)

Answer (score 0):

*I think integer mean here is ascii value of character*
so you can use again your ascii value to play with characters 
my solution is you have to type cast  your variables like this ,
and use **ord()** function to get ascii values

```
l = ['A','B','C']
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    print("string value is ",l[i])
    # now for integer values
    if type(l[i]) != 'int':
        print("ascii value of this char is ",ord(l[i]))
    else:
        print("already int type go on..")
```

as because there is no meaning of having a int value of characters , int value of character generally refers as ascii value may be *some other formats*

Answer (score 0):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to iterate both on the indices and the letters.

```
NG = ['A','B','C']

for i, n in enumerate(NG, 1):
    print(i, n)
```

Will output:

```
(1, 'A')
(2, 'B')
(3, 'C')
```

In your case, because you don't need the letters at all in your loop, you can use the underscore `_` to notify coders in your future about what your code do - it uses the len of `NG` just for the indices.

```
for i, _ in enumerate(NG, 1):
```